# How to best "sort" Tychonoff spaces, so it is mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, tychonoff-spaces

How to best "sort" Tychonoff spaces, so it is mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive?

**Why am I asking:** When describing certain mathematical phenomenon in a paper, it may be useful to go through all kinds of spaces and study different kinds of spaces behave.

**My question:** Is there any "standard" classification of topological spaces into "categories"?
I can only think of having one criteria and sorting spaces into two mutually exclusive groups (e.g. EUCLIDEAN and NON-EUCLIDEAN... or DISCRETE and CONTINUOUS... or FINITE and INFINITE.)

However, I am looking into something less aggregate, some system which would provide reasonable number of groups for the spaces and in each group there would be few examples.

**My ideas:** I thought maybe sorting the spaces according to separation axioms would be good idea? (E.g. higher separation axiom, more conditions on the space?) Or sorting spaces according to the most common topology on it? (However, this would make overlapping groups of spaces... And there are too many topologies.)

(I concentrate on Tychonoff spaces (completely regular & Hausdorff), but classifying more general types of spaces can be interesting too.)

Comment: This is too broad and opinion based.

Comment: @Jakobian TBH I was kind of struggling with how to ask this properly. But don´t you think this is an important question? The "bigger picture" in mathematics still doesn´t get enough attention imho, yet it really helps to see some perspective. I may rewrite the question somehow, but I knot know how to describe it better or more narrowly.

Comment: Separation axioms is one way. Dimension might be another. Third one would be absolutely Borel spaces - absolutly closed, $F_\sigma$, $G_\delta$, and so on. Thing is there is a lot of different ways we can compare spaces with each other, this is what topology in part is about. And it's not just in topology. And why care about some arbitrary classification? Sometimes we just want to study spaces with useful properties for our theorems to hold. This question seems pointless to me.

Comment: @Jakobian I agree with you that some classifications may be arbitrary, but it still can help different people who visit this question. It already got some positive votes as well, so I think it really could be helpful and provide new view for at least part of the community. Also, in general topology, I would say there really are some phenomena that you can study on really broad types of spaces and some concepts can "behave" differently on different structures imho.